# Protect RESTful API endpoint with parameter in headers when request to them is made

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony-2.6

Lets said I have a restful API (built on top of FOSRestBundle) open to the world and I don't want that, instead I want to secure the endpoints. This is part of my `security.yml` file:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

As you can see any can access the API so this area needs to be secured in somehow. My idea? By passing a parameter at the request header. Since my client is an iOs app then its need to take care of send that parameter when request are made to any API endpoint. The parameter is named `X-PDONE-SESSION-ID` and basically it holds a PHP session. How I can protect the API? Any ideas using this bundle or any other ideas?

Comment: http://blog.tankist.de/blog/2013/07/18/oauth2-explained-part-3-using-oauth2-with-your-bare-hands/ & Client Credentials Flow or http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html

Comment: @Rufinus both excellent articles but how to get rid of the user part? Think that I have no need users only need to define the token and store somewhere the expiration time that should be 24 hrs, I do not want to authenticate any user I just need to give access to any that send me that API key, how to achieve this?

Comment: take a closer look to the client credentials flow."This one is the most simplistic flow of them all. You just need to provide CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET." no user id, no binding with user. "If that was the Client Credentials, ACCESS_TOKEN doesn’t contain any user information association with it, therefore there can’t be any user information retrieved, as the response suggests"

Comment: @Rufinus I am confused, in [previous step](http://blog.tankist.de/blog/2013/07/17/oauth2-explained-part-2-setting-up-oauth2-with-symfony2-using-fosoauthserverbundle/) the author use a `User` entity and still the same, I am wrong?

Comment: the howto shows all possible variations, if you dont need a user, you dont need the whole user part just leave it out.

Comment: @Rufinus not sure how to leave that part behind, can you answer the post and give me some kind of explanation? I mean did you test this by yourself and got some results?